# I have a 50gb vdi image, What's the best way to host it for distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine disk and need to host it for distribution within my company. What's the best way to do so?

Can I put it on AWS S3?

Comment: What do you mean by "host it for distribution within my company"? Do you just want to let them download it as a file? Do you have a Direct Connect to AWS, or would it just be across your normal Internet connection? Or is the virtual machine disk for use within AWS?

Comment: Yeah I just need to give other employees the ability to download the file. Just a standard internet connection. The disk image is for use on company workstations - just need to get the image to their computers for use

Comment: It might be better to host it somewhere on your network. That would be faster, easier on your Internet bandwidth and cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can host your file on S3. However, there are several factors to consider.

**Cost:**

Data transfer out (download) pricing on S3 is apx $.09 per GB. This translate to about $4.50 for each download.

**Transfer Reliability:**

Downloading a 50 GB file may be problematic for some customers. I would use a zip tool and split the file into 2 - 5 GB parts to make downloading easier. You don't want to pay for a 47 GB download that failed and then the user had to start the download over again.

**Security:**

If you make the download file public, anyone can download it and you pay. Use presigned URLs or signed cookies to control who can download the file. Since the file is for internal company use, you can restict access to IP (CIDR) block ranges.

**Performance:**

Where are your users located? This will help you determine where to host the bucket(s) for downloads. You might consider CloudFront, but for files this large, they won't get cached unless you split the file into smaller pieces.

Comment: Is there a better alternative that you would recommend?

Comment: There are lots of companies that provide file distribution services. Take the major factors that I mentioned and compare each one.